# Getting Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM] for connect-redis 7.0.1

Tags: express, redis, es6-modules, connect-redis

**Node version: 16.20.2**
connect-redis version: 7.0.1
esm version: 3.2.25
redis version: 3.0.2
express-session version: 1.17.3

I am getting ERR_REQUIRE_ESM error for `connect-redis`in my node app. I have tried to install different versions for redis, connect-redis and esm. But nothing worked for me. Please help me with a solution. For your better understanding I am sharing the relevent code blocks here.

**Error:**

```
/Users/user/bidyaguru/bg-cpanel-app/server.js:1
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/user/project/myapp/node_modules/connect-redis/dist/esm/index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in null to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/project/myapp/server.js:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

My **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "server": "node -r esm server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon -r esm server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "connect-redis": "^7.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "mongoose": "^6.9.2",
    "redis": "^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

My **server.js** file:

```
import express from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import expressSession from'express-session';
import {createClient} from "redis";
import RedisStore from "connect-redis";

import connectDB from './config/db';


dotenv.config();
connectDB();
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/_status', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Server is okay');
});

// Initialize redis client.
const redisHost = process.env.REDIS_HOST
const redisPort = process.env.REDIS_PORT || 6379;
let redisClient = createClient(redisHost, redisPort);
redisClient.connect().catch(console.error)

// Initialize redis store.
let redisStore = new RedisStore({
  client: redisClient,
  prefix: "myapp:",
})

// Initialize redis sesssion storage.
app.use(
  expressSession({
    store: redisStore,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: "secret",
    cookie: { maxAge: (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30) }
  })
);


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(PORT, (err) => {
  if (err) { process.exit(1); }
  console.log(`Service is running at port ${PORT}`);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to use ESM, so use the native support provided by your Node.js version.

1. Uninstall the `esm` package.
2. Set `"type": "module"` in your package.json file.
3. Remove `-r esm` from your npm scripts.
4. Rename your **relative** imports to include the `.js` extension, e.g. `import connectDB from './config/db.js';`.

Now try running dev `npm run dev`.

You can see a working example of using ESM with `connect-redis` in the [busmap](https://github.com/morganney/busmap/blob/main/packages/api/src/index.ts#L8) repository on GitHub.

Comment: I understand your solution. But I used `esm` to avoid `.js` at the end of the file path.

Comment: Why? I would argue that `esm` allowing that is an anti-pattern since ES modules mandate the presence of file extensions. For example, in Node.js: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#mandatory-file-extensions. Also, when using relative specifiers the extension is mandatory: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-specifiers

You should just remove your dependency on `esm` and use native ES modules by adding the extension.